# Script not working on .load 'ed DIV in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

On my main page I run a jQuery to load another page on document ready like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#function-content").load(pagefunction + ".php?machineid=" + machineid);
});
```

This works perfect and loads the page content to #function-content.

On the other page I need to load a .js to make things on this page work. I do it by appending the script source to the header with som jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('head').append('<script src="../../js/some_script.js" type="text/javascript">');
</script>
```

Chrome loads this javacript file very well (IE also seems to load it) but the script is not working on the #function-content element in IE.

(the script is for sorting inside tables - but I don't think it's relevant - the script works perfect in IE when the table and the script is loaded directly on a page)

Comment: Make append in document ready function and see if it works...

Comment: Maybe it is that some event listeners applied by some_script.js are applied before the table is loaded? This would explain some... Try to append the script on success of the load() function (second parameter). If this works that means you need to load script in good order, or call a function from script when the DOM changes

Comment: first load the js then load div content.

Comment: Tried appending it inside the document ready function - still no luck. Actually it will be best to load inside the next page, as document ready can load multiple other pages that should not be using the script.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var loadjs = document.createElement('script');
       loadjs.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
       loadjs.setAttribute("src", "js/script.js");
       $('head').append(loadjs);
    });
```